# How can I add a text column to a table?

Tags: sap-erp, sap-data-dictionary

i want to add a text column to the MMBE table, it could be the lot size text field: KZTXT or any other (that is the one they are using right now, but do not want to click on it to see it, instead just see it in the front page). it will just add comments when the material has quanitites in quality inspection

thx

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible answers to your question:

- if you want to add a column to a table, you can go to the appropriate transaction (I think se11) and add the column
- the way you've worded your question it sounds like you want to display a new field in a transaction's screen. The answer to this question depends on the capabilities of the relevant SAP module, some offer pretty generic ways to define your own screens (e.g. business partner), some offer add-on capabilities (usually in a sub-menu or specific sub-screen), with most (especially if you're talking about the "front page"), you may be foreced to resort to a modification of a standard SAP screen. This can be done using the regular development tools (se80, ScreenDesigner etc.), but there is a whole other level of thinking required if you really want to go down that road.

Answer (score 0):

MMBE is a transaction, not a table.  It refers to SAP standard report RMMMBESTN.

There are several steps to take in order to add a field to the report:

1. Does the field that you want currently exist in a SAP table? If yes: go to step 3
2. If no: You have to add the field to APPEND structure of the appropriate SAP table in SE11.  In this case you have to also consider how this data is going to get into the table in the first place, who's going to maintain it etc.  (I'm not going into that)
3. If yes: You have to enhance report RMMMBESTN.  In a ECC6 System you can use any of the enhancement Spots supplied.  In earlier systems you may have to repair the program.

DO NOT copy transaction MMBE to ZMMBE and then change the program.  When you upgrade the SAP standard program may change.  If you repair a program or use enhancement spots SAP Modification assistant will help you to apply your changes to the new program - otherwise you're on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its very intersting the point you make about modifing instead of copying. One thing I will have to find out is how friendly its sap regarding "undoing" your changes or in other words to go back to the original code version.

Regards,

Comment: SAP has thorough version control - it is very simple to revert back to a previous version.  (SE80->Utilities->Versions)